# Hello guys I'm trying to install mutter rounded setting (for transparent theme customization) I can't run mutter rounded setting

Tags: gnome, mutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr7LJ.png)

This is what I receive

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; what are you using?  (*your provided picture contained details that make it look [off-topic for this site](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)*)

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting